# How to prevent onmouseover from acting like onmousemove?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I've assigned an onmouseover event to my html body. However, I only want it to fire once, when the mouse enters the body.

Instead, it's firing repeatedly, whenever I move my mouse in the body, even if the mouse never left the body.

Is there a way to prevent these misfires?

Thanks

Comment: Learn all the events you have at your disposition and their differences. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: @mwilson, what do you mean "both" events? i only want one event.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the event [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) not [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) which will be triggered when you move from element to element.

> The mouseenter event is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse)
>   is moved over the element that has the listener attached.
>
> Similar to [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover), it differs in that it doesn't bubble and that it
>   isn't sent when the pointer is moved from one of its descendants'
>   physical space to its own physical space.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  snippet.log('mouse entered')
});
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  snippet.log('mouse over')
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<div>Soem content <span>within span</span> <button>Button</button></div>
```